# How to get exact NTP drift in OS X

Tags: macos, synchronization, ntp, drift

I'm trying to get actual NTP drift on Macs connected to a local NTP server.

- When reading `/var/db/ntp.drift` file I get -37.521 which according to [PPM to milliseconds conversion](https://pthree.org/2013/10/13/ntp-drift-file/) gives **-3241ms** of drift.
- When using `ntpq -c lpeer` I get something like this:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*172-1-1-5.light 164.67.62.212    2 u   57   64  377  199.438   38.322  29.012
```

which means **38.322ms** of drift.

- Finally, `sntp 172.1.1.5` outputs this:

```
2016 Jan 21 18:41:45.248591 +0.019244 +/- 0.022507 secs
```

which means **19.244ms** of drift.

I'm confused which one of the approaches gives accurate NTP drift?

Comment: Offset and drift are not the same thing.

Comment: @dfc what is offset?

Comment: 38.322 and +0.019244 are the offset that ntp is reporting and you are thinking it is a drift value for some reason. I think you need to spend some time reading the ntp documentation if the term offset is new to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `ntpq -pcrv` that should give you all the info and more. If you need any of the output explaining then edit your question and we will try & help you out.

Remember drift is specific to your box. It looks like your NTP server is either far away or you have a poor network link (based on your delay time). You might want to try a closer ntp server.